# AutoIncremental field

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

I need to autoincrement NroFattura and AnnoFattura (this one is the year of the report):
[image: Error]

I dont know how to do it, if by C# or by Access settings.
I want that NroFattura is like n = n + 1 
And AnnoFattura is like n = get year now (function)
I have a winform behind it (C#)

Comment: I suppose that when the year changes you want to reset the NroFattura to restart from 1 right? (By the way, for non Italian speakers, NroFattura = InvoiceNumber, AnnoFattura = InvoiceYear)

Comment: Yes , like 2014 -> 1 , n+1 then 2015 -> 1, n+1

Comment: Do you have a multiuser database scenario? Or it is just a single user at time that works with the database?

Comment: Its just a single user at time

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple scenario, where only one user at time works with the database then it is simply a matter to find the highest value inserted for the `FatturaNro` in a specific year

```
 string query = "SELECT MAX(FatturaNro) FROM yourTableName WHERE AnnoFattura=?";
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", DateTime.Today.Year);
 object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 int newInvoiceNumber = (result == null ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(result)+1);
```

Comment: You should be careful about using this query, while it is running the table is locked for other sessions and this will cause lot of tablelock if you have too many records and too many transactions

Comment: @RezaRahmati single user at time in a winforms application, no threads mentioned in the question. What do you mean for _other sessions_?

Comment: I adjusted the code like that : `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd4 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(); cmd4.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text; cmd4.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(FatturaNro) FROM Fatture WHERE AnnoFattura=?"; cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", DateTime.Today.Year);`

Comment: Do not forget to set the connection property for the command, otherwise your code is equivalent

Comment: I have already 4 queries going on so the connection is already opened, isnt it?

Comment: Not opened, associated with the cmd4.Connection property, otherwise the command cannot find the database to work on.

Comment: Alright, understood. Anyway i will try propely the code later at home, so keep an eye later in that thread since im gonna ask you later if it doesnt works for something. Thank you

Comment: @steve other sessions means other users which are querying on this table no matter reports, CRUD or .., it there are few concurrent users it's OK but if there are a lot of users, it will make trouble

Answer (score 0):

The Access auto increment setting is not suitable for this kind of action. If you delete items, the counting will still countinue. For example, if you had 20 items, removed 2, the count would still move to 21 on the next insert. The auto increment field should be used as an unique id of the record, not to as "row number".

You could add a new column for unique indexes, so row specific editing is possible.
Calculating the NroFattura in C# code is easy. Shape the final insert string with the right values and run it.